# How does DesiredCapabilities in Selenium WebDriver works internally

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know How does Desired Capabilities in Selenium WebDriver works internally??

For e.g. Suppose i have 2 different version of Chromedriver.exe on my machine. While executing code with Desired Capabilities, which exe it would pick and why?

How does Desired Capabilities internally decides from which path exe should be picked??

Answer (score 0):

The DesiredCapabilities Class is used by the WebDriver instance (i.e. driver) to open the browser session with specified attributes. For example, the below code will:

1. Always use the "chromedriver.exe" from "C:\your_path\" directory.
2. Through DesiredCapabilities Class we can specify the location of the Chrome Executable.
3. Finally you need to pass the instance of DesiredCapabilities for driver to open the Chrome Application with those capabilities.

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_path\\chromedriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
   driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
   ```
4. It is always recommended to use the latest version of the drivers. The latest versions/releases of the drivers addresses the the bugs/defects of the previous build & also introduces new features. So, the idea  of using another older version of drivers are not a part of good programming practice.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I am not using .setCapability() method as i dnt want to specify location. I got the answer of my question. DesiredCapabilities searches for the "chromedriver.exe" in specific locations(approx 21 locations) if we have not mentined it. 1st location it searches is your eclipse folder jdk bin . For eg.ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\jre\bin;

Comment: @Hema can you please let me know about those 21 location sequentially. Or some documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Locations are depend on your machine softwares. For me below are the paths   ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\jre\bin;ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64//jdk1.8.0_66-x64/jre/bin/server;ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64//jdk1.8.0_66-x64/jre/bin;
ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64//jdk1.8.0_66-x64/jre/lib/amd64;Program Files (x86)\git\git1.9.5\bin;WINDOWS\system32;WINDOWS;WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;
Selenium\bin;apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;JDK1.8.0_66-X64\bin;apache-tomcat-8.0.20/bin;ECLIPSE-4.5.1-X64;